# How do I update a record in a nodejs CRUD with prisma, express and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I'm trying to create a simple API in node js with express and prisma.

I have the following model for clients in my schema

```
model Clients {
  id        String     @id @default(uuid())
  email     String     @unique
  name      String
  address   String
  tel       String
  invoices  Invoices[]
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt
}
```

I've created the all the CRUD functions and they all work fine apart from the update clients function.
This is what my clients controller looks like.

```
import { db } from '@utils/dbconnection';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Users } from '@prisma/client';
const createAClient = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const { email, name, address, tel } = req.body;

  const clientExists = await db.clients.findUnique({ where: { email } });

  if (clientExists) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Client already exists' });
    return;
  }

  const newClient = await db.clients.create({
    data: {
      email,
      name,
      address,
      tel,
    },
  });

  res.status(201).json(newClient);
  return;
};

const updateClient = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { id: userId } = req.user as Users;
  const { email, name, address, tel } = req.body;

  if (email) {
    const emailExists = await db.clients.findFirst({ where: { email } });
    if (emailExists) res.status(401).json({ message: 'Email already exists' });
  }

  const updatedClient = await db.clients.update({
    where: {
      id: userId,
    },
    data: {
      email,
      name,
      address,
      tel,
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json(updatedClient);
  return;
};
```

and these are my routes.

```
router.post(
  '/client/',
  isAuthenticated,
  asyncMiddleware(controller.createAClient)
);
router.put(
  '/client/:id',
  isAuthenticated,
  asyncMiddleware(controller.updateClient)
);
```

and this is the isAuthenticated middleware

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const { TOKEN_SECRET } = process.env;
import { Users } from '@prisma/client';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: Users;
    }
  }
}

export const isAuthenticated = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const token = req.headers['x-auth-token'] as string;
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Access denied' });

  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, TOKEN_SECRET as string);
    req.user = verified as Users;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send('Invalid Token');
  }
};
```

My authentication validator seems to also work fine if the use isnt logged in and properly returns the "Not authorised" response. But when I log and try to run the request to update the client,

localhost:5001/api/v1/client/4ad4e09a-9d9c-4b6f-aba4-1768abd02dbe

I keep getting an error.

```
Error: 
Invalid `db.clients.update()` invocation in
/Users/mcdavid/dev/projects/envoyce/envoyce-backend/src/controllers/Clients.ts:55:42

  52   if (emailExists) res.status(401).json({ message: 'Email already exists' });
  53 }
  54 
→ 55 const updatedClient = await db.clients.update({
       where: {
     ?   id?: String,
     ?   email?: String
       },
       data: {
         email: 'info@aic.ug',
         name: undefined,
         address: undefined,
         tel: undefined
       }
     })

Argument where of type ClientsWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.
```

I've tried to use the examples from the prisma documentaion on update but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried logging the userId variable right before the update call? It might be undefined, which would explain the error message.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I was using req.user instead of req.params. Fixed that so it works now

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out I was using

```
const { id: userId } = req.user as Users;
```

in place of

```
const {id} = req.params
```

as the client id in the update query.

Once I fixed that, it worked.